# Char Comparison in C

Tags: c, char, comparison

I'm trying to compare two chars to see if one is greater than the other. To see if they were equal, I used `strcmp`. Is there anything similar to `strcmp` that I can use?

Comment: How about `==` and `>`?

Comment: When you follow kerreks advice, remember to use `unsigned char`.

Comment: Kerrek's comment is the answer, unless you have some more detailed specifics that you haven't mentioned. Try giving an example in that case.

Comment: Are you comparing characters, or strings? It's unclear from your question since you mentioned using `strcmp`. Could you please provide examples of what you want?

Comment: For some reason when I deference my chars, I'm getting the ascii value of the first number. So 5 and 555 would be the same. However, when I used strcmp for checking equality, I didn't run into this issue. I'm a very strong C coder.

Comment: Well I've been working on an assignment that is storing many things. In my struct, there is a char and it could store ints or strings.

Comment: @dclark So, you are working with rather strings, like `"555"`. Tell me, how can you expect the computer to have a single value for those 3 characters? In such cases, for lexicographical sorting, `strcmp`  is what you should be using, unless you want to write your own `strcmp`. By the way, `strcmp` does tell you whether one string is *greater* or *less* than the other; negative value means first string would be found earlier in a dictionary than the second one. Refer to this for more information: [MSDN - strcmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0z9k731.aspx#returnValueToggle)

Comment: Use `strcmp()` to compare strings.  The return value is 0 if strings are the same.  The return value from `strcmp()` also indicates order: the value is < 0 or > 0 to indicate which string is _lesser_ or _greater_.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I needed for this situation. I think it might be an issue with malloc as to why I was only getting the the first number of char.

Answer (score 38):

A `char` variable is actually an 8-bit integral value. It will have values from `0` to `255`. These are almost always [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/), but other encodings are allowed. `0` stands for the C-null character, and `255` stands for an empty symbol.

So, when you write the following assignment:

```
char a = 'a';
```

It is the same thing as this on an ASCII system.

```
char a = 97;
```

So, you can compare two `char` variables using the `>`, `<`, `==`, `<=`, `>=` operators:

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';

if( a < b ) printf("%c is smaller than %c", a, b);
if( a > b ) printf("%c is smaller than %c", a, b);
if( a == b ) printf("%c is equal to %c", a, b);
```

Note that even if ASCII is not required, this function will work because C requires that the digits are in consecutive order:

```
int isdigit(char c) {
    if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') 
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is tagged with C.

Comment: Sorry about the nit: "0 stands for the NULL"?  maybe ASCII NUL or the C null character, but not `NULL`.

Comment: I am sorry for this. My mistake!

Comment: comparison operator has to be corrected above, if( a == b )

Comment: I wouldn't have seen that. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

In C the char type has a numeric value so the > operator will work just fine for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {

    char a='z';

    char b='h';

    if ( a > b ) {
        printf("%c greater than %c\n",a,b);
    }
}
```

Comment: really, so does this mean that a < B  ?

Comment: @AndrewPaulSimmons 'a' ascii code decimal 97 is NOT less than 'B' ascii code decimal 66.  If you need case sensitive comparison then use tolower() on both arguments

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are trying to compare two strings representing values, the function you are looking for is:

```
int atoi(const char *nptr);
```

or

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

these functions will allow you to convert a string to an int/long int:

```
int val = strtol("555", NULL, 10);
```

and compare it to another value.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    long int val = 0;
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s number\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    val = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
    printf("%d is %s than 555\n", val, val > 555 ? "bigger" : "smaller");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to roll your own way of comparing characters. The C standard only mandates that the digits 0 to 9 have an easy way to compare them using basic `c1 > c2` style comparison. This is NOT guaranteed to work for other characters like letters. (Although in practice it often will for simple ASCII ranges like a-z and A-Z.)

One way to do it, often unsatisfactory, is to convert the characters to strings and use `strcoll()`.