# scanf won't designate char in c, and strcmp is messing with me

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

This is a smaller segment from a project, and I'm trying to ask a char from the user.

```
void listBeer(int noRows) {
int endlessLoop = 1;
char sortChoice;
system("cls");

while(endlessLoop == 1)
{
    printf("Do you want to sort by name(n) or by product number(p)?\n");
    scanf("%c", &sortChoice);
    printf("kossan hoppade!\n");
    if(strcmp(sortChoice, "n") == 0 || strcmp(sortChoice, "N") == 0|| strcmp(sortChoice, "p") == 0 || strcmp(sortChoice, "P") == 0 ) {endlessLoop = 0;}
    else {printf("Please answer with n/N for name sorting or p/P\n");}
}
```

The console crashes during the comparison and the error code is "strcmp makes pointer from integer without a cast".

I tried using "char* sortchoice" instead but then my scanf won't do anything and the loop passes through twice before letting me enter a char.

I'm guessing I got more than one problem to solve, and I really tried smashing solutions together but it still doesn't make any sense to me.

Any explanation is appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22736348/694576

Comment: yes it did, but I switched from strcmp to what flaviodesousa recommended below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `strcmp()` use simple comparison like `sortChoice == 'n'`.

`strcmp()` is not intended for comparing single characters.

Comment: thanks! that removed all my errors, but the loop still passes through twice before letting me enter anything.

Comment: Try adding a space before `%c` like `scanf(" %c", &sortChoice);`. That removes past key presses from the buffer on some environments.