# c, how do i use a char variable in an if statement?

Tags: c

I am trying to compare a `char` a variable to a string in an `if` statement.
here's my code:

```
int main(void) {
  char x[2] = "i";
  if(x[2] == 'i'){
    printf ("x is i\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The `if` statement just ends up being false and the program does nothing.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This looks to be a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736348/char-comparison-in-c

Comment: Use x[0] instead of x[2].

Comment: `x[2]` is out of bounds of the `x` array. Indexing starts from 0!

Comment: Turn compiler warnings up: `gcc -Wall` would catch this silly typo (and the missing `<stdio.h>` header too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Char Comparison in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22736348/char-comparison-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C have a starting index of 0 and an ending index of the size minus 1.  In the case of `x`, that means that the valid indexes are `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

By indexing `x[2]`, you're reading past the end of the array.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as getting an unexpected result.  What's probably happening under the hood is that you're reading whatever value happens to reside right after `x` where it's allocated on the stack.

Since `x` contains the string `"i"`, which consists of the character `'i'` followed by a null byte (0), you instead want `x[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

`x[2]` is accessing memory beyond the array, which leads to undefined behavior. Array indexing starts at `0` in C, so an array of two elements has valid indices of `x[0]` and `x[1]`.

In your case, the letter `i` is stored at `x[0]`, so you should write:

```
int main(void) {
    char x[2] = "i";
    if(x[0] == 'i'){
        printf ("x is i\n");
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char x[2] = "i";
```

In-memory view of `x` will be something like this:

```
    +---+---+          
    | i | \0|           
    +---+---+
    x[0] x[1]
```

In your program, you are accessing `x[2]`. Accessing an array subscript out of range is undefined behavior.

Instead, you should:

```
if(x[0] == 'i'){
```